# When do you use :: and when do you use . in Rust?

Tags: rust

While playing with Rust, I came across the [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba0b4e882db425c02e8b3917f4825ba4):

```
extern crate chrono; // 0.4.6
use chrono::TimeZone;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", chrono::Local::today());
    println!("{}", chrono::Local.ymd(2019, 1, 1));
}
```

When does one use `::`, as in the first line, and when does one use `.`, as in the second line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods called with the `.` syntax are called [instance methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#defining-methods) (or just methods), while those called with the `::` syntax are called [associated functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions). The main difference is that instance methods take some form of `self` as an argument, whilst associated functions don't.

You can check the implementation of [`Local::today`](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/master/src/offset/local.rs#L85-L87) as an associated function:

```rust
pub fn today() -> Date<Local> {
    Local::now().date()
}
```

compared to [`Local.ymd`](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/master/src/offset/mod.rs#L213-L215):

```rust
fn ymd(&self, year: i32, month: u32, day: u32) -> Date<Self> {
    self.ymd_opt(year, month, day).unwrap()
}
```

One caveat here, however, is that `Local.ymd` is actually implemented as part of the `Timezone` trait, which `Local` [implements](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/master/src/offset/local.rs#L95-L152).

Another thing to note here is that `Local` is a struct with no fields. This means it can be created like `Local {}` or even just `Local`.

Comment: I think that you should emphatize the last point. That's what makes the syntax surprising: `Local.foo` vs `Local::bar`.